# Going nuts: Why is array in member class zero

Tags: java, android, constructor

I don't know what is happening here. I made a simple application that has a member class.

Here's my code that behaves as expected. Nothing fancy here. The main class initializes the member class using the constructor and calls a member method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int array[] = null;

    // Init member class
    subClass = new SubClass();
    subClass.doSomething();
}
```

And the code of the member class:

```
package com.example.test;

public class SubClass {
    private int[] array;

  public SubClass(){
    if(array==null){
        array = new int[10];
    }
  }

  public void doSomething(){
    if(array == null){
        // We don't get here, which is good.
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to pass the member class an Array, for example from an savedInstanceState. To keep the example short and tidy, I just pass an array reference that is null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int[] array = null;

    subClass = new SubClass(array);
    subClass.doSomething();
}
```

And the member class:

```
package com.example.test;

public class SubClass {
    private int[] array;

  public SubClass(int[] array){ 
    this.array = array;

    // Whatever was passed, I want to make sure we have an array to work with. 
    if(array==null){ 
    // Yes, it is null so init it. 
        array = new int[10]; 
    // FROM HERE IT SHOULD BE AN int[10] array AND NOT NULL IN THIS CLASS
    // NO MATTER WHAT THE CALLING APPLICATION DOES WITH IT'S PRIVATE
    // VARIABLE (no, not parts ;))
    }
  }

  public void doSomething(){
    // and now, array should be of 10 length but it isn't!

    if(array == null){
        // We do get here, which is wrong!
        System.out.println("array == null in doSomething");
    }
  }
}
```

If I do pass an valid array, like array = new int[1] and in the constructor ignore what is passed and just always init as array = new int[10], in the doSomething method it is an int[1] array again!

Thanks.

Comment: question v.1:  i might be wrong but array in SubClass is never initialised on constructor, since it is not null, it is empty array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(array==null){ 
// Yes, it is null so init it. 
    array = new int[10]; 
// FROM HERE IT SHOULD BE AN int[10] array AND NOT NULL IN THIS CLASS
// NO MATTER WHAT THE CALLING APPLICATION DOES WITH IT'S PRIVATE
// VARIABLE (no, not parts ;))
}
```

You're assigning `array` and not `this.array`.

`array` in this case is the method local array and not the class variable.

So:

```
if(array==null){    
   array = new int[10];
   System.out.println(array);
   System.out.println(this.array);
}
```

Would print

```
Array[..]
null
```

When you reference it later in doSomething you are referencing `this.array`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I feel so stupid now. I did a reference copy.

Comment: My programming skills are a bit rusty. I spend a few hours on it.

Comment: :) We all have been there

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value for array, whereas you need to set this.array. If you only set array, the old value was null so there is no way it will copy over to the class member variable.

A null reference has no effect, a reference only copies between variables if they are accessing the same address, in this case they are not because both were null before you initialized array. If you had initialized array before assigning it to this.array then they would both have the same reference and you could use them interchangeably till the constructor method returned.

Comment: the compiler will search for the first matching variable name (starting with most limited scope) so it finds array before this.array. I find it useful to __always__ be explicit when referencing variables